# Filter or Set Parameter programmatically on Report(rdlc)

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I created a report(not wizard) on VB2010, and I set the Datasource using Dataset programmatically, I want to add a filtering option to the report

[image: Dataset]

[image: Tablix Filter Properties]

**ORIGINAL CODE:**
this code show all the data with no filtering

```
Dim rptDataSource As ReportDataSource


            With rptReportViewer.LocalReport
                .ReportPath = "Reports\" & strReport & ".rdlc"
                .DataSources.Clear()
            End With

            Select Case strReport
                Case "rptProducts"
                    Dim ds As New dsProducts
                    Dim da As New dsProductsTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter

                    da.Fill(ds.Products)

                    '//use the same name as defined in the report Data Source Definition
                    rptDataSource = New ReportDataSource("ProductsDataSet", ds.Tables("Products"))

            End Select

            rptReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDataSource)
            rptReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
            rptReportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent
            rptReportViewer.RefreshReport()
```

I do some googling and I insert the some code

**MODIFIED CODE**

```
        Dim rptDataSource As ReportDataSource
        **'this code inserted**
        Dim FilterBrand As New ReportParameter("FilterBrand", txtfilter.Text)


            With rptReportViewer.LocalReport
                .ReportPath = "Reports\" & strReport & ".rdlc"
                .DataSources.Clear()
            End With

            Select Case strReport
                Case "rptProducts"
                    Dim ds As New dsProducts
                    Dim da As New dsProductsTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter

                    da.Fill(ds.Products)

                    '//use the same name as defined in the report Data Source Definition
                    rptDataSource = New ReportDataSource("ProductsDataSet", ds.Tables("Products"))

            End Select

            rptReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDataSource)
            **'this code inserted**
             rptReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {FilterBrand})
rptReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
            rptReportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent
            rptReportViewer.RefreshReport()
```

The report says error occur during report processing, what is problem, how to i set the filtering programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an expression in your Filter Value:

```
=Parameters!FilterBrand.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the previous answer, you can follow the following example:
[image]

[image]